# UWP- How to get Local Machine certificates?

Tags: uwp

How can we access Local Machine certificates in UWP? `CertificateStores::FindAllAsync` is not working. It works for the user store.

Comment: Does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/certificates

Comment: I saw that, but it's not very clear. It says app should have access, but it's in the "Certificate storage per app container" section. Not sure what the container means

Answer (score 1):

To certs from the Local Machine store, you could Use [FindAllAsync(CertificateQuery)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.cryptography.certificates.certificatestores.findallasync#Windows_Security_Cryptography_Certificates_CertificateStores_FindAllAsync_Windows_Security_Cryptography_Certificates_CertificateQuery_). Pass store name through Certificate query like this:

```
    var query = new CertificateQuery();
    query.StoreName = "ROOT";
    return CertificateStores.FindAllAsync(query)
```

FindAllAsync() only get certificates from the App’s store. If the app has shareusercertificates capability, this call will also retrieves certs from the User store.